# iOS Framework Delegate and IBAction are not getting called in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, objective-c-framework

I am creating one framework in Objective-C.
I have everything working fine in Objective-C project.
But when I Integrate my framework with Swift project, it behaves strange.

My Swift Project:

- Just one ViewController and one button with IBAction connected.

Now:

- In `viewDidAppear` I have initialized my framework and set `delegate` to `self`.
- Once I get initialized successful delegate called, I call another method.
- but the strange behaviour is everything stopped, even `IBAction` is not working.

But when I tried to add NSTimer repeat method in viewDidAppear, everything working fine again.

I know this is very weird issue but might be someone has faced this.

My Code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    MySDK.sharedInstance().initWithAppKey("123")
    MySDK.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Delegate calls,

```
//This is getting called
func initSdkSuccessful() {
    MySDK.sharedInstance().doStuff()
}

//This is not getting called
func stuffDone() {

}
```

IBActions,

```
//This is getting called if I do not set delegate,but if I set delegate to self then It doesn't.
@IBAction func btnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    MySDK.sharedInstance().doAnotherStuff()
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the MySDK side of this, there's not much to go on.

Comment: @Avi, The issue is only with delegate, when none of `delegate` called then `IBAction` is getting called, but when any of `delegate` called then nothing working. Might be issue of background thread etc...

Comment: It might be a lot of things.  That's the point -- without source, we can't hope to help except by luck.

Comment: :(, I see, But it is very strange...The same thing is working if I only use my .h,.m files, but not working in .framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution which was really very simple one,

**Just changed my delegate from `weak` reference to `strong`, that's it.**

Might be The issue was, when one of delegate method got called then delegate object was becoming nil, as it was `weak` reference.